# API is showing [object, Object] instead of just the fact text

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a random cat fact app that generates a cat fact when you click on the image. I am trying to grab the random cat fact from the API https://catfact.ninja/fact but when I do it shows up in my div as [object, Object]. I am a beginner coder and would like some help on API handling.

[image: Picture of my web app and the console]

Here is my js code:

```js
const url = "https://catfact.ninja/fact";

async function getAPI(url){
    const response =  await fetch(url);
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    showFact(data);
}
getAPI(url);
function showFact(data){
    document.getElementById("fact").innerHTML = "<b>" + data + "</b>";
}
```

```css
.fact {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#logo {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: block;
}
h1, h2{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Random Cat Facts!</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Random Cat Facts</h1>
<img id="logo" src="catfact.jpg"/>
<h2>Click the cat for a random fact!</h2>
<div id="fact">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I removed the 'java' tag - java and javascript are as related as ham and hamster. (As in, they are 2 completely different things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In conclusion, just replace `data` to `data.fact` in `showFact` function.

`document.getElementById("fact").innerHTML = "<b>" + data.fact + "</b>";`

To be more specific;

While evaluating `"<b>" + data+ "</b>"`, js compiler calls `data.toString()` function to append the object `data` to string. Note that only string can be appended to string by the `+` operator. As long as your `data` object from the API response includes the element `fact` with string type, you should point this element to be appended,

Comment: WOW this was such an easy fix! Thank you!

Comment: Just updated my answer to be more specific. Hope you learned at least something.

Answer (score 0):

In this function

```
function showFact(data){
    document.getElementById("fact").innerHTML = "<b>" + data + "</b>";
}
```

you are putting `data` directly on the page, which is an object. To show the actual fact, you need to access the data in the object. It should probably look like this-

```
function showFact(data){
    document.getElementById("fact").innerHTML = "<b>" + data.fact + "</b>";
}
```